# For which type VScode conditional breakpoints with an expression work in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, conditional-breakpoint

I'm trying to use conditional breakpoints on a C++ project but it's not easy. After a lot of tries I managed to find out conditional breakpoints works with int and double. I previously tried to use them with strings and chars and it didn't work but at least now I know it works with numbers type. However, I wanted to know if it was all

I've just read the conditional breakpoints part of the VScode manual : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_conditional-breakpoints but it doesn't provide clear examples or the list of types which are compatible with conditional breakpoints.

Is it possible to make conditional breakpoints works with other types than int and double ?

Thx

PS : I use g++ 9.3.0

Comment: What would be the condition of interest for, say, a `std::string`?

Comment: related GDB docs (I'm pretty sure GDB is the underlying tool powering the debugging here): https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Conditions.html

Comment: Ah ok I see. VScode just uses gdb and gdb can't use conditional breakpoints with compound types (like std::string for instance).